# div with width:100% are different

Tags: html, css

I have some divs all set to width:100% on my website:

```
<div id="participate" class="test">
  participate
</div>

<div id="description" class="test">

  <div id="brief" style="display:table-cell">
&nbsp;
  </div>

  <div id="price" style="display:table-cell">
&nbsp;
  </div>

</div>

<div id="bottom" class="test">

  <div id="partners" class="test">
&nbsp;
  </div>

  <div id="content" class="test">
&nbsp;
  </div>

</div>
```

Only #bottom has set display:table. When I set border I see #border is smaller excatly 2px than others div.

When I set #border width:100.3% it is ok however this solution seems retarted to me. The problem is present in chromium and absent in firefox.

Why is that and how can I get rid of it?

Any hint'll be appreciated.

Comment: divs inside of other divs are bound by their parent.  If the outer div has padding or border, the 100% width on the inner div will only fill to what's available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing

`div` elements default to `box-sizing: content-box`, in which `border`s *are not* part of the `width`.

In Chrome, setting `display: table` forces `box-sizing: border-box`, in which the borders *are* part of the `width`.

This is shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wsEkc/

The easiest way to make the two `div`s consistent is to apply `box-sizing: border-box` (and its vendor prefixed variants).

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/wsEkc/3/

Comment: Unfortunately, box-sizing alone has not solved the problem. I used box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */ what is suggested on w3schools website. That's do the job.

Comment: Well yeah, that goes without saying :) I left them out to improve the formatting of my answer, but I included them in the final jsFiddle demo.